# how to download music with asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have an asp.net webform application. I want to have a button for downloading musics, so I write below code block :

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string id_new;
    id_new = Session["selectedmusicID"].ToString();
    DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
    dt2 = blm.selectMusic("sel_music", Convert.ToInt32(id_new));
    string test = dt2.Rows[0][9].ToString();
    Response.ContentType = "application/mp3";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", dt2.Rows[0][9].ToString());
    Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath( dt2.Rows[0][9].ToString()));
    Response.End();
}
```

When I run this code and click on button it downloads the music.aspx page not mp3 file.I don't know what is my mistake.
Anyone can help me?

Comment: @baty , what are you getting on `dt2.Rows[0][9]` ??

Comment: dt2.Rows[0][9] is the address of path that music save in it.for example '../music/musicname.mp3'

Comment: @baty show the format how it would be

Comment: ../music/musicname.mp3

Comment: @baty this line `Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", dt2.Rows[0][9].ToString());` change to  `Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + name);` here `name` is `musicname.mp3`

Comment: it worked but download file not mp3.the suffix of file that was downloaded is .file not .mp3

Comment: @baty means ? i didn't get you

Comment: @Webruster He means download worked but the file format is not .mp3 but .file. Probably a formatting is needed.

Comment: I mean the file format is not .mp3! it is .file

Comment: @baty try to change the content type  `audio/mp3`

Comment: I changed the type audio/mp3 . when i click on download button a window opened in firefox that have 2 options. one of them is open with media player but another is save . when I select save, format is not .mp3 it is .file.

Comment: @baty how u sending the `Response.Transmitfile`

Comment: @Webruster I don't understand what you mean. Please explane

Comment: @baty in `Response.Transmitfile`  you need to specify the path where your  audio resides , just check you doing that correctly

Comment: I chack it.It was true.

Comment: @batty you need to specify like this ex: `c:/audio/` you doing the same? paste your latest code after changes

Comment: @Webruster this is my latest code but it throws exception (access to path is denied)
          Response.TransmitFile(@"C:\download");
            Response.End();

Comment: @baty `C:` full of restriction try to specify other folder and see, another thing what i would be doing is , just right click on the `download`  folder and uncheck the readonly mode

Comment: I try another folders and also unchecked the readonly mode but it throws exception

Comment: @baty try to specify `@D:\\audio.mp3`

Comment: @Webruster It throws exception (access is denied)

Comment: @baty ckeck this [link](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Save-MP3-Audio-Files-to-database-and-display-in-ASPNet-GridView-with-Play-and-Download-option.aspx)

Comment: @Webruster , I checked this link. you know I have a folder named music in my project folder i.e in site root there is a folder named music and all of the musics stored in it. when I use server.mappath(../music/musicname.mp3) it returns c://users//pro//desktop//project//music//musicname.mp3. so when my site is uploaded this address is not valid ! another problem : I convert music file to byte and used response.binarywrite but it does not usefull . my problem does not solved

Comment: @baty you got way many issues !!  only thing that left in my bag is  give appropriate permission to your audio folders

Comment: duplicate?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40501135/how-to-generate-code-for-download-a-music-mp3-in-asp-net-c (or, the link is a dup of this?)

Comment: . I did not get answer so I asked again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've solved my problem, as you can see in the code below...
first I create a column named MusicByte to my music table in database.I stored the data of every music by file uploading in this column...

```
string id_new;
id_new = Session["selectedmusicID"].ToString();
DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
dt2 = blm.selectMusic("sel_music", Convert.ToInt32(id_new));
string test = dt2.Rows[0][9].ToString();
string filename = test.Substring(9).Replace(" " , "").Replace(".mp3" , ".MP3");
byte[] buffer = (byte[])(dt2.Rows[0][10]);
Response.ContentType = "audio/mpeg";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "Attachment;filename=" + filename);
byte[] datablock = new byte[0x1000];
long filesize;
int bytesread;
long totalsbytesread = 0;
using (Stream st = new MemoryStream(buffer))
        {
            filesize = st.Length;
            while (totalsbytesread < filesize)
            {
                if (Response.IsClientConnected)
                {
                    bytesread = st.Read(datablock, 0, datablock.Length);
                    Response.OutputStream.Write(datablock, 0, bytesread);
                    Response.Flush();
                    totalsbytesread += bytesread;
                }
            }
        }
        Response.End();
```

deleting spaces in filename and replice the .mp3 to .MP3 was usefull.Also this video in you tube helps me : Upload and download files to/from a SQL Server database