# how to generate code for download a music (mp3) in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a asp.net webform application (music website).
I want to have a download button. So when users clicked on that. selected music start to download with browser.How can I do that?

here is the code that I tried:

```
string id_new;
id_new = Session["selectedmusicID"].ToString();
DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
dt2 = blm.selectMusic("sel_music", Convert.ToInt32(id_new));
string test = dt2.Rows[0][9].ToString();
string test2 = test.Substring(9);
Context.Response.Clear();
Context.Response.Buffer = true;
Context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + test2);
Context.Response.ContentType = "audio/mp3";
Context.Response.TransmitFile(@"~\music\" + test2 );
Context.Response.End();
```

[see this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZazd.png)

Comment: Have you tried to do anything?

Comment: yes I have written a code for that but musics saved with .file format not .mp3
I write my code in question

Comment: The test2 substring you are doing, is that trimming the .mp3 from the filename. If so then that is your issue. The value passed to the filename part of the content disposition is the one you will see in your browser. If this has no extension it is downloaded as .file.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
int id = int.Parse(context.Request.QueryString["id"]);
byte[] bytes;
string contentType;
string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
string name;

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "select Name, Data, ContentType from tblFiles where Id=@Id";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id);
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        sdr.Read();
        bytes = (byte[])sdr["Data"];
        contentType = sdr["ContentType"].ToString();
        name = sdr["Name"].ToString();
        con.Close();
    }
}

context.Response.Clear();
context.Response.Buffer = true;
context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + name);
context.Response.ContentType = contentType;
context.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
context.Response.End();
```

If you're not using database then try this:

```
string FileName = dateTimeStamp + "SiteReservation.doc";

if (FileName != "")
{
    System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(path + dateTimeStamp + "SiteReservation.doc");

    if (file.Exists)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=SiteReservation.doc");
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
        //Response.End();
        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("This file does not exist.");
    }
}
```

Comment: In database I have a table for musics that columns are ID,Musicname,Singer,DatePublish,path(the path that music save in it for example: ../music/musicname.mp3) I do not have data column.

Answer (score 1):

try this,you may get an idea

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       Response.ContentType = "Application/mp3";
       Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=filename.mp3");
       Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~\Location\filename.mp3"));
       Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: I tried this code it worked but after download musics have .file format not .mp3!